# An approximation of the sign function

Tags: functional-analysis

Define $T_k(x) = \max\{-k, \min(x,k)\}$.

Informally, drawing its graph, I can see that $\lim_{k \to 0}\frac{1}{k}T_k(x) = \text{sign}(x)$. In what senses does the convergence hold? Similarly, the limit as $k \to 0$ of its derivative should be identically zero.

I think $\text{sign}$ is not really a proper function. =So how best to think of it (for the context of PDEs)?

Comment: You can write ${1 \over k} T_k(x) = \max(-1, \min({x \over k},1))$, so the only region it differs from $\operatorname{sgn}$ is $|x| \le k$. The $\operatorname{sgn}$ is a function, albeit not-continuous. The functions $T_k$ are continuous, and differentiable at zero, but $T_k'(0) = {1 \over k}$ which is unbounded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you have pointwise convergence.

Then again, it should easy to prove that we also have the convergence in the sense of $L^p_{loc}$, $1\le p < \infty $, and, therefore, in the sense of distributions. These convergences will be the most useful for PDEs.

Finally, you can't have uniform convergence.

If you have some other convergence in mind, ask in comments.

Comment: Thanks. Am I correct that $\lim_{k \to 0}T_k'(x) \equiv 0$? How do I deal with showing this because it is equal to $\frac{1}{\epsilon}$ on $(-\epsilon, \epsilon)$, and I don't know how to take limit..

Comment: @riem: The limit is infinity, not zero. See my comment above.

Comment: @copper.hat Thanks. I guess you mean limit is infinite at $x=0$. I guess it's not too bad for PDE since mostly only care about $L^p$ convergence and we can discount that point.

Comment: @riem: Correct, I was a little sloppy. Since ${1 \over k} T_k$ agrees with $\operatorname{sgn}$ on $|x|>k$, the derivative must be zero there.

Comment: @copper.hat Do you know if $\frac{1}{k}T_k' \to 0$ in $L^p$ as $k \to 0$? It converges p.w. a.e to $0$, but I can't use DCT since there is no domination.

Comment: @riem: You can evaluate $\|{1 \over k} T'_k\|_p = \sqrt[p]{2} k^{{1 \over p} -1}$, hence the answer is no.